# Code should not be auto capitalised

Tags: support, status-norepro, code-formatting, editor

When writing code out in answers if I need a for loop I will often default to just using `i` as the loop variable. However, this can be very annoying as then the editor helpfully capitalises the I. I know why it does this but it shouldn't for code.

So for the feature request: The editor should not capitalise, spell correct<sup>1</sup>, grammar correct<sup>1</sup> etc. anything in code.

---

<sub>1. I'm not sure if it does do spell or grammar checking, but if it does it shouldn't.</sub>

Comment: That's not the editor. That's your own OS or browser. The Stack Overflow editor does **not** autocorrect anything.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've tried in comments, search, google and other sites and the `I` is not capitilsed

Comment: I don't know how your OS or browser picks what text to edit. The Stack Overflow editor however, *never does this*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay, must just be coincidence that I couldn't find something else that did this.

Comment: Without OS and browser details, we can't help you further with disabling this. I see that support differs from OS to OS and from browser to browser.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't need support in disabling it, I thought it was a feature of the editor and hence the feature-request. If I wanted support disabling it I wouldn't be asking on SO Meta.

Comment: Well, now that you know it is not the editor, you might have wanted to know, *while we are here anyway*. And future visitors with the same idea might want to know too!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fair enough, re-reading my previous comment it was a bit hostile so sorry for that, I don't need to know but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That'll be your browser or your operating system. The editor on Stack Overflow does not do this.

For example, if you're using Windows 10, there's an *Autocorrect misspelt words* setting.